# Delete where one column contains duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

consider the below:

```
ProductID  Supplier
---------  --------
111        Microsoft
112        Microsoft
222        Apple Mac
222        Apple
223        Apple
```

In this example product 222 is repeated because the supplier is known as two names in the data supplied.

I have data like this for thousands of products. How can I delete the duplicate products or select individual results - something like a self join with SELECT TOP 1 or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: You can do it with one DELETE. Just one thing, back it up first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do the following:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This selects an arbitrary row for each product.

To delete all rows but one, you can use the same idea:

```
with todelete (
      (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by product_id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
        from t
      )
delete from to_delete where seqnum > 1
```

Comment: Gordon, your select statement fits my need perfectly - thank you. Is there a way to use the max seqnum of the group to effectively get the latest result? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Supplier, MIN(ProductID) min_ID
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY Supplier
        ) b ON  a.supplier = b.supplier AND
                a.ProductID = b.min_ID
WHERE   b.Supplier IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a14af/1)

or if you want to delete `productID` which has more than onbe product

```
WITH cte 
AS
(
    SELECT  ProductID, Supplier,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY Supplier) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/456b6/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH Products_CTE AS
    (
    SELECT ProductID, Supplier,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY <some value>) as rn
    FROM PRODUCTS
    )

SELECT *
FROM Products_CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

The `some value` is going to be the key that determines which version of Supplier you keep.  If you want the first instance of the supplier, you could use the DateAdded column, if it exists.